# Understanding the placement of closing tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, packery

I need help understanding why the first set of code works, whereas the second code doesn't.

In the first set of code, I am able to drag and drop elements and still have them in [Packery](http://packery.metafizzy.co/draggable.html#jquery-ui-draggable) flow when dragging, which is the result of the `tree.packery()` line. In the second code, that doesn't work, meaning when I drag the elements, they don't fall back in order.

**The only difference is that in the first set of code, the `draggable()` and `tree.packery()` methods are placed within the closing tags of imagesLoaded. What bothers me is why this is necessary to make `tree.packery()` work?**

**1** `tree.packery()` is inside the closing tag of imagesLoaded

```
var fruit = $('.fruit');

fruits.imagesLoaded(function() {
    var tree = fruits.packery({
        itemSelector: '.fruit',
        columnWidth: 0,
    });

    fruit.draggable();

    tree.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', fruit); // this line works!
}); // imagesLoaded closing tag at the end
```

**2** `tree.packery()` is **not** inside the closing tag of imagesLoaded

```
var fruit = $('.fruit');

fruits.imagesLoaded(function() {
    var tree = fruits.packery({
        itemSelector: '.fruit',
        columnWidth: 0,
    });
}); // imagesLoaded closing tag

fruit.draggable();

tree.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', fruit);
// this line doesn't work this time
```

Answer (score 2):

imagesLoaded is probably asynchronous. It means that when you call it, it returns immediately, and continues to execute the next lines of code. At the point `tree.packery( 'bindUIDraggableEvents', fruit );` is run, it's entirely possible the callback you pass to imagesLoaded has not run yet, so tree is actually not initialized.

Does it make any sense?

The important point is that the code you pass as a callback to `imagesLoaded`

```
var tree = fruits.packery({
    itemSelector: '.fruit',
    columnWidth: 0,
});
```

is not run immediately. It is run whenever the internal code of `imagesLoaded` decides to call it (which is probably once all the images have loaded).

If you want to learn more about callbacks and closures (which is another important concept that is relevant to your question) in javascript, this article seems like a good start: http://javascriptissexy.com/understand-javascript-callback-functions-and-use-them/

Comment: It's even worse.  Besides the proabable async issue, the `tree` variable is defined within the callback function scope so it's not even available for the `tree.packery()` function call in the second code block.

Comment: I think I understand now. It's like a long one-way street with only one exit on both ends. Along this street, the code can pick up errands, some errands require it to return to that particular point of the street a second time(callback), but it has to walk through the entire street before it can return.

A callback can only be made on a 'second trip' due to the nature of the "one way street". So any code that requires the item provided by the callback cannot be put outside of this 'second trip'.

Comment: @blurgoon, This is not entirely accurate because there are cases where a callback will be invoked immediately. Let's stick to your example. You can think of it that way: the callback will run sometime in the future, after the images are loaded. Must the thing I want to do occur after the the images are loaded? If the answer is yes (and it's definitely yes if you need to use the argument sent to the callback), than you need to place your code inside the callback.

Comment: Do you mean it depends on the context of the function that invoked the callback? Like for imagesLoaded, clearly it will have to wait for all images to be loaded. Whereas if it were a click() function, it would be invoked after a click. Am I right?

Comment: and to play it safe, variables should never be created in a callback and used outside of it unless certain that the callback will be invoked quickly before the next line of code runs.

Comment: Regarding your first question, you are right but that wasn't my point. My point was that sometimes your callback will run before the code that comes after the function (in your example `fruit.draggable();`). It really depends on the specific function. In your example, it could maybe happen if all the images were already loaded somehow.

Comment: Regarding your second question: If you need to use a variable outside the callback NEVER declare it within the callback EVEN if you're sure it's invoked before (although for 99.9% of the cases you can't be sure). The reason is that the variable won't be available for the code outside the callback. This is due to the callback having its own scope. Check the link in my answer for more info about this concept, which is very important to understand.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87689/discussion-between-blurgoon-and-bumpy).